# Angular10 table with selection - show expanded row when checked

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, angular-components

I am using angular 10 table with selection but want to show an expandable row when the row is selected. I have tried using the expandable tables along with the selection table but it hasn't worked.

I have added my html code below, but the row is always visible on the page. I only want it visible when the row is checked.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
        [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
        [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element"
      [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length"
    >
      Show when checked
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    (click)="selection.toggle(row)"
  ></tr>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show/hide the second template row based on your selection state.

Look back at the material example, you'll notice that they use CSS to set the expanded row height to 0, then change the overflow and display to flex for expanded rows.

Here is a different but more quick example of wrapping your expanded row inside an ng-if that checks the same selection mechanism your checkbox uses. I have not run this, it is an example. You can switch the ng-if to do toggle display: none or visibility, however understand that using those methods will impact how long it takes your table to render.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
<td
  mat-cell
  *matCellDef="let row"
  [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length"
>
  <ng-container *ngIf="selection.isSelected(row)">
    Show when checked
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you. using `*matCellDef="let row"` solved this for me.